# BigQuery Join on Calculated Field

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, calculated-columns

I'm trying to join two tables on a calculated field:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(year, mo, da) AS date,
  temp
FROM
  [bigquery-public-data:noaa_gsod.gsod2016] AS a
JOIN
  [bigquery-public-data:noaa_gsod.stations] AS b
ON
  a.stn = b.usaf
  AND a.wban = b.wban
JOIN
  [test-project:0000.ga_sessions_20161002] AS c
ON
  c.date = CONCAT(a.year, a.mo, a.da)
WHERE
  b.name = "DUBAI INTL"
ORDER BY
  a.year ASC,
  a.mo ASC,
  a.da ASC
```

I keep getting the following error:

> ON clause must be AND of = comparisons of one field name from each
>   table, with all field names prefixed with table name

I presume this error is a result of the second ON statement but I've prefixed all field names with their table name.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of using table a, use a subquery that performs the desired function for you.  As an aside, is c.date a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) for the query instead. Once you do (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options") you can run e.g.:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(year, mo, da) AS date,
  temp
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod2016` AS a
JOIN
  `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.stations` AS b
ON
  a.stn = b.usaf
  AND a.wban = b.wban
JOIN
  `test-project.0000.ga_sessions_20161002` AS c
ON
  c.date = CONCAT(a.year, a.mo, a.da)
WHERE
  b.name = "DUBAI INTL"
ORDER BY
  a.year ASC,
  a.mo ASC,
  a.da ASC;
```

Here's a standalone example that doesn't rely on the `ga_session` table, too:

```
WITH MyTable AS (
  SELECT '20161003' AS date UNION ALL
  SELECT '20160830'
)
SELECT
  CONCAT(year, mo, da) AS date,
  temp
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod2016` AS a
JOIN
  `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.stations` AS b
ON
  a.stn = b.usaf
  AND a.wban = b.wban
JOIN
  MyTable AS c
ON
  c.date = CONCAT(a.year, a.mo, a.da)
WHERE
  b.name = "DUBAI INTL"
ORDER BY
  a.year ASC,
  a.mo ASC,
  a.da ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I was a little confused why you added the `MyTable` definition at the top but it made sense after I looked up the `UNION ALL` operator. I think it's better to revert to using the `ga_sessions_20161002` table in your answer just so it's more clear how the answer directly relates to the question.

Comment: Sure, I updated the example to use your original tables, though I also left the standalone example in case other readers want to try it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a subquery:

```
FROM (SELECT a.*, date(CONCAT(a.year, a.mo, a.da)) as yyyymmdd
      FROM [bigquery-public-data:noaa_gsod.gsod2016] a
     ) a JOIN
     [bigquery-public-data:noaa_gsod.stations] b
     ON a.stn = b.usaf AND a.wban = b.wban JOIN
     [test-project:0000.ga_sessions_20161002] c
     ON c.date = a.yyyymmdd
```

Or something like this . . . the exact comparison might depend on the type of `c.date`.

Answer (score 0):

The JOIN you're using is an INNER JOIN by default, so the ON clause can only do simple equality on the columns.

To work around you'll need to use a CROSS JOIN with a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(year, mo, da) AS date,
  temp
FROM
  [bigquery-public-data:noaa_gsod.gsod2016] AS a
JOIN
  [bigquery-public-data:noaa_gsod.stations] AS b
ON
  a.stn = b.usaf
  AND a.wban = b.wban
CROSS JOIN
  [test-project:0000.ga_sessions_20161002] AS c
WHERE
  b.name = "DUBAI INTL"
AND
  c.date = CONCAT(a.year, a.mo, a.da)
ORDER BY
  a.year ASC,
  a.mo ASC,
  a.da ASC
```

Comment: This will mean computing the entire cross product of the two tables prior to filtering, though. It would be better either to compute `CONCAT(...)` in a subquery prior to the `INNER JOIN` or else to use [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/).